# Evitar que mi texto desborde el contenedor flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Por algun motivo mi texto sigue desbordandose de mi DIV, no se si sea porque es un contenedor `Flex` pero no encuentro como hacer que se adapte, le intente de todas las formas y no logro hacerlo.

```
<a href="#">
<div class="image image1">
    <div class="margin">
            <p class="tittle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis, voluptate?</p>
            <p class="hidden">Vamos a comprar pan</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.general-info {
margin: 50px;
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
padding: 0px;
white-space: nowrap;
text-align: center;
}

.image {
position: relative;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 270px;
max-height: 500px;
width: 50%;
min-width: 300px;
padding: 10px 11px 12px 10px;
max-width: 500px;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
object-fit: cover;
}

.image::before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: rgb(206, 83, 77, .6);
transition: 2s;
opacity: 0;
}

.image:hover::before {
opacity: 1;
transition: .6s;
z-index: 7;
}

.image1 {
background-image: url("../../../public/img/general-info/girasoles.jpg");
}

.image2 {
background-image: url("../../../public/img/general-info/bosque.jpg");
}

.margin {
position: inherit;
display: flex;
align-items: flex-end;
height: 100%;
border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
z-index: 10;
word-break: break-all;
}

.margin .tittle {
position: relative;
color: white;
width: 300px;
bottom: 5px;
left: 5px;
font-size: 30px;
z-index: 10;
transition: .6s;
text-transform: uppercase;
word-break: break-all;
}

.image:hover .margin .tittle {
bottom: 25px;
transition: .6s;
}

.image .margin .hidden {
position: absolute;
left: 7px;
bottom: -10px;
color: white;
opacity: 0;
transition: .6s;
}

.image:hover .margin .hidden {
opacity: 1;
transition: .6s;
z-index: 7;
bottom: 5px;
transition: .6;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que se cree una segunda linea de texto pero que no se salga de la caja sino que siga creciendo hacia arriba como en la segunda imagen

Comment: El código que compartes no replica el problema, lo cuál hace difícil responder a la pregunta.

Comment: Por favor crea un [example]

Comment: Que te gustaría que suceda con el texto si supera el tamaño del padre?

Comment: Perdon, no me habia dado cuenta que el codigo no explicaba bien. Pero ahi tienen todo el codigo...

Comment: Lo que me gustaria es que el texto vaya creciendo pero hacia arriba, osea, el "lorem ipsun... " suba y debajo se escriba lo que no cupo en la primer linea.  No se si me explico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu regla css de `.general-info` cambia el `white-space` a `inherit` o directamente elimínalo, ya que no parece que estés usando ese atributo.

```css
.general-info {
margin: 50px;
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
padding: 0px;
white-space: inherit;
text-align: center;
}

.image {
position: relative;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 270px;
max-height: 500px;
width: 50%;
min-width: 300px;
padding: 10px 11px 12px 10px;
max-width: 500px;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
object-fit: cover;
}

.image::before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: rgb(206, 83, 77, .6);
transition: 2s;
opacity: 0;
}

.image:hover::before {
opacity: 1;
transition: .6s;
z-index: 7;
}

.image1 {
background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520209759809-a9bcb6cb3241?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aW1nfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&w=1000&q=80");
}

.image2 {
background-image: url("https://www.imgacademy.com/sites/default/files/2009-stadium-about.jpg");
}

.margin {
position: inherit;
display: flex;
align-items: flex-end;
height: 100%;
border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
z-index: 10;
word-break: break-all;
}

.margin .tittle {
position: relative;
color: white;
width: 300px;
bottom: 5px;
left: 5px;
font-size: 30px;
z-index: 10;
transition: .6s;
text-transform: uppercase;
word-break: break-all;
}

.image:hover .margin .tittle {
bottom: 25px;
transition: .6s;
}

.image .margin .hidden {
position: absolute;
left: 7px;
bottom: -10px;
color: white;
opacity: 0;
transition: .6s;
}

.image:hover .margin .hidden {
opacity: 1;
transition: .6s;
z-index: 7;
bottom: 5px;
transition: .6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="general-info">

        <a href="#">
            <div class="image image1">
                <div class="margin">
                    <p class="tittle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis, voluptate?</p>
                    <p class="hidden">Vamos a comprar pan</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>

        <a href="#">
            <div class="image image1">
                <div class="margin">
                    <p class="tittle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis, voluptate?</p>
                    <p class="hidden">Vamos a comprar pan</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>

    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Eres Dios. Muchas gracias bro, eso lo soluciono todo! Sabia que era una sola cosita que debia cambiar.